# Add option to filter felon friendly employers to promote equal opportunity

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

While looking around on Linkedin, I noticed that last year they rolled out a feature called [the Fair Chance job filter.](https://blog.linkedin.com/2020/february/new-ways-to-bring-equal-access-to-opportunity) This feature, in their words, will "help job-seekers easily identify employers who have committed to consider applicants with a criminal record, thus removing a major barrier from their job search process."

I thought this would be a great feature for SO to consider, as it would benefit a largely forgotten branch of the community.

Comment: This.... looks very US-centric? (The LinkedIn article also mentions about "United States only")

Comment: How would this be more beneficial in the context of established EEOC laws?  I ask this because the EEOC side of things [directly addresses the inequities of a conviction with respect to the largely forgotten branch of the community](https://www.eeoc.gov/laws/guidance/enforcement-guidance-consideration-arrest-and-conviction-records-employment-decisions#IV).